# Can you create folders to organize web sites in IIS7?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have several ASP.NET sites in IIS7 and would like to be able to group them into folders (or other mechanism, if available).  Ideally, I would use a customer name or account number and put the sites under there.

Is there a way to customize the organization of sites in IIS7, or is there just the one 'flat' view?

I'm open to tricks and hacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS7 (or any other version) does not have the concept of folders for sites. I would instead come up with a naming scheme that, on sorting the list of sites, makes it easier to find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

One option will be to add multiple applications under one site if they are related and on same domain of course. You can also have each applicatoin associates to its own application pool.

For example,

www.example.com

www.example.com/admin

www.example.com/auth